# How to mock or ignore validation errors raised while instansiating settings object for optimization in fastapi

Tags: python

I have the question that is complex to describe in words for me, so I'd better provide a code snippet for you:

Imagine we are building FastAPI project for example and use pydantic's BaseSettings:

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    ...
```

So, not to instansiate the object of Settings class in every use case I do the following:

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    ...
settings = Settings()
```

The problem is that when I test my code there raised a lot of validations errors and I have no idea on how to prevent this without providing env variables through the os.environ.

The problem is that the test code looks like this:

```
from ... import ...
import ... as ...
os.environ['some_env_variable'] = 'some_value'
from ... import ...
```

Comment: I would recommend either using `pytest-env` to set the necessary variables, or to give your settings default values (I sometimes default settings to what they should be in my local env, and then override them in test/stage/prod environments).

Comment: Variables isn't the main problem. I use FastAPI and the're some dependencies which are located in the "advances" section in docs. So, they are initialized per application and are used to store the state or execute the role of cache. I have such dependencies and they perform http requests. So, I need to somehow mock these requests

Comment: There is nothing about dependencies or mocking in your question. If that's your real concern, I suggest you delete this question and ask a new one.